# Divide table data in 4 parts in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have a table say `Offers` with the following data

```
Id   Name
1    A
2    B
3    C
4    D
5    E
6    F
7    G
8    H
9    I
```

I do have 4 `containers` also which holds these `offers`.

Now what i wanna to create a data structure like

```
Class Data 
{
    Public int containerID {get; set; }
    public ICollection<Offers> offers { get; set; }
}
```

I want to iterate through this `offers` table and assign each offer one by one to container.

E.g  Offer `A` goes to `Container1`, `B` goes to `Container2`, `C` goes to `Container3`,`D` goes to `Container4`. Again `E` goes to `Container1` and so on.

I want `list` of class `Data` type in my scenrio.

I have tried the following code but i know i am no where near the solution.

```
 var data = context.tbl_offer.Where(x => x.INT_IS_PRIME == 1 && x.DAT_START_OFFER <= dat && x.DAT_END_OFFER >= dat)
                      .Select(z => new { 
                          offerID = z.Id,                             
                          offerName = z.Name

                      });
```

Any thoughts ?

Comment: You want to select all data from this table ?

Comment: Yup.. But in future i may need to filter out some data from `Offers` table

Comment: Try `context.tbl_offer.Select(z => new { 
                          offerID = z.Id,                             
                          offerName = z.Name

                      });`

Comment: I think you haven't read my requirement in complete. I need structure like defined in `Data` class. I need `Container ID` with `Offers` in it.

Comment: please  provide the offers and containers data model. i assume that there is a container primary key going to the offers as the fk

Comment: container does not have any data modal. it has pre assumes that  there are 4 container with ID 1,2,3, an 4 . relevant `Offer` data modal has been described above alreay

Comment: Are containers created before running the query or you can create them during the query? for example set their Id= 1,2,3,4?

Comment: `Container` does not exist conceptually in data base. I just need to break `tbl_offer` data in 4 parts with `containerID` 1,2,3 and 4

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it seems you can use a group by. like I did in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it seems you can use a group by:

```
var result = list.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i % 4 + 1, Value = x })
                 .GroupBy(x => x.Index)
                 .Select(x => new Data()
                 {
                     containerID = x.Key,
                     offers = x.Select(a => a.Value).ToList()
                 });
```

Using this data:

```
var list = new List<Offers>{
    new Offers(){Id=1, Name="A"},
    //...
    new Offers(){Id=9, Name="I"},
};
```

The result would be:

```
Group 1: A, E, I
Group 2: B, F
Group 3: C, G
Group 4: D, H
```

Comment: If `Id` of `offer` would be inconsistent i.e  not in sequence of running counting. then Group 1 may have less offers than others. But ideally it should have 3

Comment: You can change the query to use an index instead of the Id

Answer (score 0):

```
//select data
var data = context.tbl_offer.Where(x => x.INT_IS_PRIME == 1 && x.DAT_START_OFFER <= dat && x.DAT_END_OFFER >= dat);

var containers = new List<Data>();
//add 4 containers
containers.Add(new Data() {
    containerId = 1,
    offers = new List<Offers>()
});
containers.Add(new Data() {
    containerId = 2,
    offers = new List<Offers>()
});
containers.Add(new Data() {
    containerId = 3,
    offers = new List<Offers>()
});
containers.Add(new Data() {
    containerId = 4,
    offers = new List<Offers>()
});

//assign the offers to the containers
for(int i = 0; i < data.Count(); i++){
    int index = i % containers.Count;
    containers[index].offers.Add(data.ElementAt(i));
}
```

Keep in mind that you cannot use an anonymous class if you need instances of `Offers`. Therefore I removed

```
Select(z => new { 
    offerID = z.Id,                             
    offerName = z.Name
});
```

Comment: `Cannot  implicitly convert tbl_offer to  Data` . Where is `container ID` ? We can't add `tbl_offer` type in `List<Data>`

Comment: @RajeevKumar sorry, made a mistake inside the for loop. Its fixed now

Answer (score 0):

So if you see as per your description every 4th record(if you consider the starting index 0) will go into Container1. So Container1 will contain A,E,.

So you could build a generic logic which will fetch you container 1 to 4 items like this only your nth value will vary.

```
int nth=4;
var container1ids = context.tbl_offer
            .Select(x => x.Id)
            .ToArray()
            .Where((x, n) => n % nth == 0)
            .ToArray();
```

Now query offers which contains these ids to get container1 records

```
var conatiner1Records = context.tbl_offer.Where(x => container1ids.Contains(x.Id));
```

Hope this helps.